# Translating text within controller with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, translation, angular-translate

Im using angular translate and need to translate some words in the controller. Im using json files for translation in the html.

```
// LABELS
var monthNames = [
    "Janvier", "Février", "Mars",
    "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet",
    "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre",
    "Novembre", "Décembre"
];
//some code here
title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'Commandes'
}
```

Comment: provide the full solution that you tried in order to get a proper solution

Comment: im using tranlate filter on html {{"word" | translate"}} it works and want to do the same for those words in my controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject **$filter** service in your controller and then you are free to use itwith any service ( in this example with the translate service )

```
const translation = $filter('translate')('HELLO_WORLD'); // HELLO_WORLD is the definition from the translation json file
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can define an plus level on monthNames Objects with the language you need

```
var monthNames = {
  "fr-fr": [
    "Janvier", "Février", "Mars",
    "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet",
    "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre",
    "Novembre", "Décembre"
  ]
},
```

Comment: im using this implementation in my main controller
self.language = "FR";
 self.toggleLanguage = function() {
  self.language = self.language == "FR" ? "EN" : "FR";
  $translate.use(self.language);
 }